# URDF correct in RVIZ but wrong in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, rviz

I'm trying to build a dual-arm model that I want to use with MoveIt etc. later, my URDF works correctly in RVIZ but for some reason that does not work in Gazebo. I'm also getting the following Warning, but not sure if it's related:

> [gzserver-1] Warning [parser_urdf.cc:390] attempted to add visual
> [arm_0_base_link_inertia] to link [arm_0_base_link], but it already
> exists in visual_array under name [arm_0_base_link_inertia]

That's the way I'm trying to spawn:

```
ros2 run gazebo_ros spawn_entity.py -topic robot_description -entity ur5e
```

And below you can see my problem. The arms are happily dangling around, but in the wrong place. The base of the UR Robots spawns correctly connected to the dual-arm-base.

[image: Comparison RVIZ with Gazebo]

Am I missing something really obvious or can something give me a hint for what I should be looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot give you an answer to your question but I can give you my opinion. Get rid of gazebo. Install and try webots instead.

Comment: Is there anyway that you can provide a reproducible example of the code you are running? In a github repo or linked the relevant files? Thanks.